# wordpress woocommerce within products filtering taxonomy by another taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filtering, redirection-wordpress-plugin

Is it possible to create such a search filter with WordPress? I am explaining it to you. This is an eCommerce car site. Here is a taxonomy that can be filtered by brand model and generation. When I filter by brand model and generation, a search results page opens. And here are the other categories on the show. Supposedly, the categories of accessories that the car has under the brand are shown with dynamic. These are the accessories like the body, suspension, interior steering, etc. Basically, these categories are shown within this brand or model and generation. Let me tell you that search result pages can be created and used in WordPress. But the search result page can also show categories. However, the filtering cannot be done hierarchically. I've taken a taxonomy of categories under Products in WordPress for brand models and generations. Another taxonomy is body suspension steering for these. Now I want to filter the brand model generation like off-road-express site so that car accessories are shown. I think possible that's way connect to you. I am also using crocoblock with all plugin.

This is example site url: https://offroad-express.com

i am try to slove by plugin

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to create a search filter with WordPress that allows users to filter products by brand, model, and generation, and then display categories of accessories based on the selected criteria. To achieve this, you can use custom taxonomies, custom post types, and plugins, such as the Crocoblock suite of plugins. Here's a general outline of the steps you can follow:

**1. Create Custom Taxonomies:**

- Create custom taxonomies for brand, model, generation, and accessory categories. You can do this using the Crocoblock suite or custom code in your theme's functions.php file.

**2. Create Custom Post Types:**

- Create a custom post type for products or accessories, and associate them with the custom taxonomies you created in step 1.

**3. Create a Search and Filter Interface:**

- Use a plugin like JetSmartFilters from Crocoblock to create a search and filter interface on your site. You can create filterable elements for brand, model, and generation.

**4. Hierarchical Filtering:**

- To implement hierarchical filtering, you'll need to use a plugin or custom code that supports multi-level filtering. JetSmartFilters may be able to handle this, but you might need to configure it accordingly. Ensure that the filtering is done hierarchically to match your requirements.

**5. Display Results:**

- Create a search results page template where the filtered results are displayed. You can customize the template to show product or accessory categories based on the selected brand, model, and generation.

**6. Dynamic Category Display:**

- To dynamically display accessory categories based on the selected criteria, you may need to use custom queries in your template. Query the custom post types associated with the selected brand, model, and generation, and display the relevant accessory categories.

**7. Styling and Layout:**

- Use the Crocoblock plugins or custom CSS to style and format your search results page, ensuring that it matches the design of your site.

**8. Testing and Optimization:**

- Test the functionality to ensure that the filters work as expected and that the categories are displayed correctly. Optimize the performance of your site to handle the dynamic filtering efficiently.

Keep in mind that this is a complex task that may require some development and customization work, especially when it comes to hierarchical filtering and dynamic category display. Crocoblock's suite of plugins can be a helpful tool, but you might need to extend their functionality or write custom code to achieve your specific requirements.

If you're not comfortable with custom development, you may want to consider hiring a WordPress developer with experience in creating complex filtering systems and custom post types. They can help you implement this functionality effectively.